# How do I access a prop passed to TabNavigator within tab screen?

Tags: react-native

I have a tabnavigator like so

```
var TabNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
    NearbyScreen: { 
        screen: Nearby
    },
    FindScreen:{
        screen: LandmarkNavigation
    },
    NotificationScreen:{
        screen: Notifications
    },
    MyProfile:{
        screen: MyProfile
    }
})
```

that is rendered in the component

```
render() {
        //console.log(this.props);
        var nearbyLocations = this.props.locationsNearby;
        return(
            <TabNavigation thisThing="thisThingValue" />
        )
    }
```

How do I access the value of the prop I passed on  inside one of it's tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with screenProps:

```
return(
            <TabNavigation screenProps={thing} />
        )
```

Which made it accessible in the navigator tab view via this.props.screenProps

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing through here this.props.navigation.state.params.thisThing